# Including Third-Party Libraries in my Map-Reduce Job (using distributed cache)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

In my mapper code I am using a 3rd party library of JTS.jar.  I need to put it on the distributed cache of hadoop so that all nodes can access it. I found at [this](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) link that -libjars can be used to do this.

I now execute my code using

`hadoop jar -libjars JTS.jar my_jar.jar classname inputFiles outputFiles`.

but this doesn't work. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Specifics?  Are you getting a NoClassDefFoundError?  And where?

Comment: trying to execute my jar file using the above command on hadoop 0.20.2 fails by throwing "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: -libjars". It seems that -libjars is not supported at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a different effort, I tried to follow [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) link.

1) I copied the Jar library to hadoop using:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal JTS.jar /someHadoopFolder/JTS.jar
```

2) I then modified my Configuration as below:

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJobName("TEST JOB");

    List<String> other_args = parseArguments(args, job);

    DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/someHadoopFolder/JTS.jar"), conf);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(myMapper.class);
    //job.setCombinerClass(myReducer.class);
    //job.setReducerClass(myReducer.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);   
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


    String inPath = other_args.get(0);
    String outPath = other_args.get(1);     
    TextInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inPath);
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outPath));

    TextInputFormat.setMinInputSplitSize(job, 32 * MEGABYTES);
    TextInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(job, 32 * MEGABYTES);

    job.setJarByClass(myFile.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

3) The tutorial then says "Use the cached file in mapper" so my mapper looks like this:

```
    public static class myMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{
       private Path[] localArchives;
       private Path[] localFiles;

       public void configure(Configuration conf) throws IOException {
         localArchives = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheArchives(conf);
         localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
       }



    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            //ENVELOPE IS FROM THE JTS.JAR library
        Envelope e1 = new Envelope(-180, 85, 180, -85);
            context.write(key, value);

    }

}
```

Despite doing all these, The code still fails by throwing "Class bout found". Any help?

Comment: Using DistributedCache in the manner described is not the same as linking to classes in jars (e.g., referring directly to `Envelope`).  The javadoc there, incredibly, fails to mention that the only way to "use" the archives and files is via java I/O (i.e. `FileInputStream`).  I'm sure there are fancy class-loading techniques you could use, but I recommend sticking with -libjars for  what you're trying to do (which does most of this same stuff behind the scenes).

Comment: good to know that this doesn't work. I spent 4-5hrs on this trying to make it work. hope I can figure out the -libjars soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the right order of command line params.  I think the error message is pretty suggestive.

```
hadoop jar my_jar.jar classname -libjars JTS.jar inputFiles outputFiles
```

Comment: this time the job starts but it throws "class not found" which means the library was not accessed. I think that is because whatever comes after "classname" is passed to my code as arguments. Thus, -libjars is not considered at all.

Comment: http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

Comment: Check if the jars were distributed, or spit something to stdout in the driver code, to confirm that the -libjars argument is indeed getting parsed correctly.  Are you using JTS anywhere besides in the Mapper/Reducer?

Comment: could you please elaborate on how I should check whether jars are distributed?   Also, I only use JTS in mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am little late, well one way of doing this is to copy the jar files under the installation folder of the hadoop. As, I have done XXX.jars(Third party jars) in the /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common and then added this files as the external jar files.

This solved my issue, if you dont wanna do this way the other way would be to include the directory/file path of the external jar files in the export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/XXX/example.jar:...