# image processing ( template matching ) on hadoop javacv code

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop

Running a javacv code of template matching on hadoop but getting below error , please help

```
hduser@anuj-laptop:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -rmr /user/hduser/out
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Deleted hdfs://master:54310/user/hduser/out
hduser@anuj-laptop:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar back.jar back /user/hduser/in        /user/hduser/out
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

12/11/27 19:42:47 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the      arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
12/11/27 19:42:47 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/11/27 19:42:47 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
12/11/27 19:42:47 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/11/27 19:42:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201211271649_0022
12/11/27 19:42:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/11/27 19:43:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201211271649_0022_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$CvArr
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:820)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:865)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:891)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapperClass(JobConf.java:947)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
... 14 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 21 more

    12/11/27 19:43:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201211271649_0022_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201211271649_0022
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 7
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=42747
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=8
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=8
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
    12/11/27 19:43:26 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201211271649_0022_m_000000
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
at back.main(back.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

My javacv code is given below :

```
  import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;

  import java.io.File;
  import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
  import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
  import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvPoint;
  import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvSize;
  import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
  import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CvHistogram;

  import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;

  public class back {

//private static String[] testFiles = new String[] {"my.jpg","my1.jpg"};
 // private static String testFilespath = "/home/student/Desktop/images";
private static String testFilespath ="images";
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
  {
   private Text image = new Text();
   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private final static IntWritable zero = new IntWritable(0);
   public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
     {  
        String line = value.toString();
     // for (String identifier : testFiles)
     //  {
    //  FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(testFilespath+"/"+"my.jpg");
 //Document doc = builder.createDocument(fis, identifier);
    //FileInputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream(testFilespath + "/" + identifier);
        //BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(fis);
        String f=testFilespath+"/"+line;
        IplImage src_img = cvLoadImage (f, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        f=testFilespath+"/"+"my1.jpg";
        IplImage tmp_img = cvLoadImage (f, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        IplImage src_planes[]={null,null,null};
        IplImage src_hsv,tmp_hsv,dst_img;
        CvHistogram hist;
        int i, hist_size[] = {90};
      float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
      float ranges[][] = { h_ranges };
      CvSize dst_size;
      CvPoint min_loc=new CvPoint();
      CvPoint max_loc=new CvPoint();
      //0,src_planes1,src_planes2;
        IplImage tmp_planes[]={null,null,null};
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            src_planes[i]=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize (src_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            tmp_planes[i] = cvCreateImage (cvGetSize (tmp_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
         //   src_planes1=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize (src_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
          //  tmp_planes1 = cvCreateImage (cvGetSize (tmp_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
           // src_planes2=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize (src_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
          //  tmp_planes2 = cvCreateImage (cvGetSize (tmp_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
          //cout<<"I"; 
            }
        src_hsv= cvCreateImage (cvGetSize (src_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
      tmp_hsv = cvCreateImage (cvGetSize (tmp_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    //            CanvasFrame canvas1 = new CanvasFrame("sreeeee");
    //  canvas1.showImage(src_hsv);
      cvCvtColor (src_img, src_hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
      cvCvtColor (tmp_img, tmp_hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    //  CanvasFrame canvas2 = new CanvasFrame("sczx");
    //  canvas2.showImage(src_hsv);
      cvSplit(src_hsv, src_planes[0], src_planes[1], src_planes[2], null);
      cvSplit(tmp_hsv, tmp_planes[0], tmp_planes[1], tmp_planes[2], null);
      //   f=testFilespath+"/"+"my1.jpg";
      //  IplImage tmp_img = cvLoadImage (f, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
 //     CanvasFrame canvas2 = new CanvasFrame("pix");
 //   canvas2.showImage(src_hsv);
  hist = cvCreateHist (1, hist_size, CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges, 1);

 // IplImage.PointerByReference planesPointer = new IplImage.PointerByReference(tmp_planes);
  cvCalcHist(tmp_planes, hist, 0, null);
  // (5)探索画像全体に対して，テンプレートのヒストグラムとの距離（手法に依存）を計算します． 
  dst_size =
    cvSize (src_img.width() - tmp_img.width() + 1,
            src_img.height() - tmp_img.height() + 1);
  int n=src_img.width() - tmp_img.width() + 1;
  int g=src_img.height() - tmp_img.height() + 1;
//  System.out.println("dfsd"+n+"dfgdfgdf"+g);
  //- tmp_img.width() + 1);

 image.set(line);
 int flag=0;
  if(n>0 && g>0)
  {dst_img = cvCreateImage (dst_size, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
//  CanvasFrame canvasr = new CanvasFrame("klkhj");
//  canvasr.showImage(dst_img);

  cvCalcBackProjectPatch (src_planes, dst_img, cvGetSize (tmp_img), hist,
                          CV_COMP_CORREL, 1.0);
 // CanvasFrame canvas3 = new CanvasFrame("pixkjhkjh");
 // canvas3.showImage(src_hsv);
  double[] min_val={0};
  double[] max_val={0};
//  min_loc.x()=10;

cvMinMaxLoc(dst_img, min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc, null);
  //    System.out.println("vxcvxc "+min_val[0]+"   "+max_val[0]);
  //    System.out.println("vxcvxc "+max_loc.x()+"   "+max_loc.y());
  //    System.out.println("vxcvxc "+min_loc.x()+"   "+min_loc.y());
  ***strong text***//   System.out.println("vxcvxc "+tmp_img.width()+"   "+tmp_img.height());
// (6)テンプレートに対応する位置に矩形を描画します． 

if(max_loc.x() !=0 && max_loc.y() !=0)
  { cvRectangle (src_img, max_loc,
               cvPoint (max_loc.x() + tmp_img.width(),
                        max_loc.y() + tmp_img.height()), CV_RGB (255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
    flag=1;
  }
 // cvNamedWindow ("src", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 // cvNamedWindow ("dst", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   //     CanvasFrame canvas4 = new CanvasFrame("sad");
//  canvas4.showImage(src_img);
  //CanvasFrame canvas5 = new CanvasFrame("lkj");
  //canvas5.showImage(dst_img);
  //CanvasFrame canvas6 = new CanvasFrame("jkl");
  //canvas6.showImage(src_hsv);
//  cvWaitKey(0);

//  cvDestroyWindow("Image");

  cvReleaseImage(dst_img);
  cvReleaseImage(tmp_img);
  cvReleaseImage(src_hsv);
  cvReleaseImage(tmp_hsv);
  for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    cvReleaseImage(src_planes[i]);
    cvReleaseImage(tmp_planes[i]);
//    cvReleaseImage(src_planes1);
//    cvReleaseImage(tmp_planes1);
//    cvReleaseImage(src_planes2);
//    cvReleaseImage(tmp_planes2);
  }


  }
  if(flag==1)
   {
    output.collect(image,one);
    line = "/user/hduser/output/"+line;
    cvSaveImage(line, src_img);
    cvReleaseImage(src_img);
   }
  else
   output.collect(image,zero);

  //System.out.println("key value pair   "+line);
      // }
     }
  }

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       int sum = 0;
       while (values.hasNext()) {
         sum += values.next().get();
        // System.out.println("jkgj"+key+"nbnbmnbmnb"+sum+"jghgjhgjhg");
       }
       output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(back.class);
     conf.setJobName("back");

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
     conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

     JobClient.runJob(conf);
   }


}
```

Comment: You could probably start with the layout of your code to keep overview. Makes the code much better readeble and helps you prevent errors

Comment: Have you tried to include the libraries of OpenCV in a JAR file, in a manner similar to the case of an applet: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/HowToMakeAnApplet ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are experiencing looks like your jar file does not include all of the required dependencies -- specifically, the openCV jar.  There are two ways of resolving this error:

1. putting the required jars in the distributed cache ( see [Including Third-Party Libraries in my Map-Reduce Job (using distributed cache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463366/including-third-party-libraries-in-my-map-reduce-job-using-distributed-cache))
2. creating a jar with all of your dependencies included.  The second way is very easy to accomplish with maven. Maven will also help you resolve all of your dependency issues before it will let you do anything.  This is usually mis-interpreted as maven not "just working".  The problem is that if maven doesn't "just work", then there are complexities in your environment that you don't understand that will cause you problems later.